# Cloud foundry multi process

Tags: architecture, cloud-foundry

I'm designing an application for cloud foundry.

Is it best practice to split an application at its service "seams" to different processes, I.e each service to run on a (possibly multiple) different process(s)?

If so, what the best way to communicate between those processes? Removing through an MQ service? How does that stand upgrades of specific service (which may break the Java API)?

If not, does it mean I should run all services for in every DEA? Wont the overhead be catastrophic?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not much of an authority on Java but yes, some sort of message queueing is perfect for communicating between different instances of an application, RabbitMQ or Resque for example.

I am not sure what you mean by your last statement, DEAs are responsible for running an instance of an application, they don't have any influence on how services are run.

Answer (score 1):

You may find this deck by one of the Cloud Foundry Developer Advocates useful - http://www.slideshare.net/chris.e.richardson/decomposing-applications-for-deployability-and-scalability-cf-india-julyaugust-2012

As Dan mentions, RabbitMQ is an obvious solution to the need to communicate between instances and parts of an application, and comes "for free" as part of the Cloud Foundry service stack. That doesn't mean that other protocols are never appropriate, but certainly something like a messaging layer can improve scalability by enabling horizontal scale-out much more simply.